# Sending string to LCD function, how does it work?

Tags: c, arrays, string, atmel, lcd

Could anyone explain to me what this function is doing? I understand it is used to display text on an LCD but I do not exactly understand how it works.

I want to send a volatile integer to the LCD and would like to understand how this function works before attempting to do so. I would appreciate any efforts to explain this to me.

```
void LCD_Send_String(uint8_t ch[])  // Send a string to the display.
{
    volatile int i=0;
    while(ch[i] != 0)
    {
        LCD_Send_Data(ch[i]);
        i++;
        _delay_us(80);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand C null-terminated char arrays?

Comment: Please show how you call the `LCD_Send_String` function. Also we cannot really know what the `LCD_Send_Data` does, we can only guess.

Comment: It loops and sends one character at a time, with a delay in between. What else is there to understand? Unless your question is why the iterator is declared as `volatile`. That is indeed a good question. Looks like remains from a debug build that someone forgot to remove.

Comment: "I want to send a volatile integer to the LCD" - then your code is completely wrong. The code shown is very basic. How about learning C instead of relying on others explaining/doing your assignment?

Answer (score 0):

ch[] is a character array(string to be transmitted) and string is send to lcd, letter by letter using ch[i] to refer to each letter.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to "send a volatile integer to the LCD" do you mean you want the LCD to display a number? If so then you'll need to use something that converts that number to a character array, before passing it as a parameter into this function.

There are various functions such as `sprintf` that will convert from an integer to a char array, if you have access to those libraries. Other answers cover its usage as well as the documentation.

Comment: Sorry I did not word my question properly, that is correct I wanted to display a number on an LCD and increment/decrement that value so yes I wanted to know how to convert that number into a character. 

I have solved this issue now but thank you for your help

Comment: Sure thing. If my answer was useful to you please upvote it. :)

I would also recommend looking up `itoa()` and related functions, should be found in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Will do once my reputation is high enough!